# Flutter: How to get data back after pushReplacement removed a route?

Tags: flutter

So it goes like this. Let's say I want to get the data of the address, title, postal code and the coordinate pin point.

I want to make the user click on a button that brings them to the second page an asks for coordinate pinpoint first, then in the third page, I will ask for their title, address, and postalCode.

CreatePreloved -> PinPointPage -> AddressPage

However i want the user the user to not go back to PinPointPage after they have submitted their coordinate so I used `pushReplacement`.

CreatePreloved -> AddressPage

```
                   Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ShoppingCreatePrelovedAddressPage(
                          pickResult: result,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
```

Then in the AddressPage the user can edit the pinpoint so I changed the function after the user choosed the pin in PinPointPage

CreatePreloved -> AddressPage -> PinPointPage

```
                 if (widget.initialPick != null) {
                    Navigator.pop(context, widget.initialPick);
                  } else {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ShoppingCreatePrelovedAddressPage(
                          pickResult: result,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
```

The problem is I cannot pass the data back to the `CreatePrelovedPage`

```
                 Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ShoppingCreatePrelovedPinPage(),
                    ),
                  ).then((value) {
                    log('value: $value');
                    if (value != null) { //value is null
                      setState(() {
                        _addressModel = value;
                        log('value: $value');
                      });
                    }
                  });
```

It says the value is null. How to pass back to data to the `CreatePrelovedPage`?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try in following method

CreatePreloved -> AddressPage

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
               ShoppingCreatePrelovedAddressPage,
              arguments: result,
            );
```

and here need to use arguments by calling following code CreatePreloved -> AddressPage -> PinPointPage

```
final result = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
               ShoppingCreatePrelovedAddressPage,
              arguments: result,
            );
```

again same logic applies below send arguments while navigating
note:use routes in main.dart to navigate

```
final result = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                    ShoppingCreatePrelovedPinPage,
                  arguments: result,
                );
```